# Unity: How to use all CPU cores for Camera.Render with Multi-threaded Graphics Jobs? Optimisations - not working?

Tags: multithreading, performance, unity-game-engine, rendering, cpu

**How to use Multi-threaded Graphics Job optimisations?**

I have a project (less of a game, more of an application) which uses many tens of cameras in a scene, all rendering at one time. (Don't ask why, it has to be this way!)

Needless to say, when running the application, this nearly maxes-out one CPU core since the rendering pipeline is single-threaded. It drops the frame rate very low as a result. (GPU, memory etc are well below 100% load - the CPU is the bottleneck here)

I was greatly relieved to see that Unity has an option called "Graphics Jobs (experimental)" which is specifically designed to split the rendering across multiple threads, and as such, multiple cores.

However, with this option enabled and DirectX12 set at the top of the graphics APIs list, I would expect that the CPU can now be fully utilised, namely all CPU cores can be engaged in active rendering. However, it seems to still be that the application is still only utilising around 40% of my CPU's potential whilst delivering a low frame rate. Surely, it should only drop the frame rate once it has maxed out the CPU? It doesn't seem that the individual cores are being used any differently. Why can I not maximise the output frame-rate by utilising close to 100% of all cores on my CPU (in total, including any additional programs which are running)?

Essentially I would like to know how I can get Unity to use all of my CPU cores to their full potential so as to get as high a frame rate as possible whilst having as many cameras in my scene at once... ...I thought Graphics Jobs would solve this? ...Unless I'm using them incorrectly or not using the correct combination of settings?

As an aside, my CPU is a i7-4790 @3.6ghz and my GPU is a 980Ti using DX12. 32gb of RAM.

Comment: Graphics Jobs enables GPU instancing (it does not automagically make your application use multiple CPU cores). You will have to implement CPU threading yourself.

Comment: @FilipVondrášek Thanks for your comment. Please note, I am not talking about making my program multi-threaded; of course this is down to the programmer to implement. I am referring to render calls for each camera in the scene - I believe Graphics Jobs is designed to put the (CPU bound) render calls on multiple threads.

Comment: It is true that Graphics Jobs take off some load from the main thread, but it is not what would help you in your case - it takes particles, sprites, flares, halos, lines and trails off the main thread. It will, unfortunately, not distribute your cameras across CPU threads.

Comment: @FilipVondrášek So how would you propose improving the performance of my application? The GPU is far from being fully utilised and it's clear that one of the CPU cores (presumably running the main thread) is fully utilised where the others are not. My understanding is that allowing the draw/render calls to happen on other threads would free up the main thread and allow the GPU to be fully utilised to return full frames back to the CPU. Thanks again for your help here.

Comment: @BenHaywayrd I don't propose anything, I'm just explaining why Graphics Jobs won't be able to help you in this very case. :) It offloads particles, sprites, flares, halos, lines and trails. Not draw calls.

Comment: @FilipVondrášek Thank you for this info Filip. Is there any way that I can maximise my CPU and/or GPU, given my situation described above? Camera.Render is the bottleneck and results in neither piece of hardware being used to its full potential.

Comment: My knowledge of this is very limited, but maybe Render Textures might be able to help you: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RenderTexture.html

Comment: Thank you @FilipVondrášek for your suggestion. Unfortunately RenderTextures are already being used, but they would not improve the performance. A camera (optionally) renders to a rendertexture so the same call stack is involved in rendering. In my setup I require many multiple cameras all rendering out to a separate rendertexutre.

Answer (score 1):

During camera render, your CPU has to talk to the GPU, in what is called a [drawcall](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DrawCallBatching.html). Under the hood, Unity is already using a multi-threaded approach ([ctrl+f "threads"](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/temas/performance-optimization/optimizing-graphics-rendering-unity-games)) to get the CPU to talk to the GPU, and this process of dealing out tasks to worker threads takes place in a black box. Note that, "Not all platforms support multithreaded rendering; at the time of writing, WebGL does not support this feature. On platforms that do not support multithreaded rendering, all CPU tasks are carried out on the same thread."

So, if your application is bound by the CPU, then perhaps your platform is not supported, or the tasks simply can't be broken down into small enough chunks to fill up all your cores, or some other 'black box' reason, like maybe the CPU is iterating over each camera sequentially, instead of batching the bunch (this makes sense to me because the mainthread has to be the one to interface with the Unity API in a threadsafe manner to determine what must be drawn).

It seems that your only option is to read the links provided here and try to optimize your scene to minimize draw calls, but with that being said, I think trying to render 'tens of cameras' is a very bad idea to start with, especially if they're all rendering a complex scene at a large resolution with post processing, etc. - though I've never tried anything like it.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your answer. I realise not all systems are supported yet, but since I am running DX12 on a Win 10 x64 PC, I should be using the only system which IS supported! Unfortunately, there is no way that I can avoid using multiple 10s of cameras in this particular setup. My application is not a game, and it requires very bizarre resolutions. Th odds are not in my favour! It's a shame I cant batch the draw calls. There is so much wasted performance potential it seems.